# Each iteration replaces the previous?

Tags: python

Also the last line gives:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
import sys
for i in range(1,123):
    if i%2 ==0:
        sys.stdout = open('log1.txt', 'w')
        print(i)
sys.stdout.close()
```

How to fix these things?

About the first issue, only the last insertion is printed in the txt while it should show all the insertions.

-**UPDATE**

```
folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE")
shapefiles = []
for shpfile in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
    try:
        shapefiles.append(geopandas.read_file(shpfile))
    except FionaValueError as ex:
        if not os.listdir(shpfile):
            sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')
            print(f'{shpfile} is empty')
```

can you tell me how to write this printed result to a txt?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? just write some even number to a file? if so: `with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file: file.write('some text')` should get you started. forget about `sys.stdout`.

Comment: You don't have to open your file every time you come across an even number. Use a [`context manager`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers) instead and do all your work in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct one is should be like :

```
with open('log1.txt', 'a') as myFile:
    for i in range(1,123):
        if i%2 ==0:
            myFile.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Correcting your code looks like:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('log1.txt', 'a')
for i in range(1,123):
    if i%2 ==0:
        print(i)
sys.stdout.close()
```

**You should open file outside of iteration. You are overriding existing file with write mode.**

File now contains :

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
42
44
46
48
50
52
54
56
58
60
62
64
66
68
70
72
74
76
78
80
82
84
86
88
90
92
94
96
98
100
102
104
106
108
110
112
114
116
118
120
122
```

Comment: I just corrected the OP's code, it is not my code actually.

Comment: Can you also write how to solve more difficult situations like the one in the updated code?

Comment: @user10154844 you can always use with open('log.txt') and write your log into it with the above example.

Comment: if you replace 'a' with w you'll see that the one with the 'w' is the correct and with 'a' gives very weird result. Check this out

Comment: a means append, w write. If file exists w overrides file. 'a' is just appends if exists creates otherwise. I think consider to what you want exactly and use the correct open file mode. Take a look at : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: I am informed about it. I am saying that if in the upper code which is the correct version you run it it will write weird result and if you put 'w' it is gonna print what you wrote as the result. Just run it once with 'a' and once with 'w'. Only the upper code you wrote.

Comment: I test it with both version and they give the same output as shown at the answer. I could not see where is the weirdness @user10154844

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit a lot from list comprehensions, consider this below:

```
[str(i) for i in range(1,123) if i%2 == 0]
```

It creates a sequence of strings. You can then go ahead and glew it with join.

**Full example**

```
with open('log1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(i) for i in range(1,123) if i%2 == 0]))
```

Comment: Using list comprehension for such a task is memory efficient? What if data size was too big?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it with the updated code  in the question?

Comment: why then not just `range(2,123,2)`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist That is ofc a good question. But this example shows how you can use an if-statement in a list comprehension. There might be more conditions to meet and then the step is not sufficient.